# Woocommerce add the product category as a class to the li

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a small Woocommerce shop, and I would like to have a sorting function. 
The sorting works like a charm, but it is sorting based on the products class.
So I would like to post the product category as class on the list item in my product loop.
My loop looks like this:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => 999
      );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } 
    else {
      echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

It outputs list items for each item like this:

```
<li class="post-15 product type-product status-publish hentry first instock">
    <a href="http://shop.bbpixelz.dk/product/i-phone-ai-template/">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="http://shop.bbpixelz.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/iphone-ai-template-150x150.png" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="iphone-ai-template">
        <h3>I-Phone Vector Template</h3>
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">$2</span></span>
    </a>
    <a href="/?add-to-cart=15" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="15" data-product_sku="ai-iphone" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</a>
</li>
```

I want to add the product category as a class to the li. How is this done?

Comment: Use this `get_the_category(get_the_ID());` inside the loop...

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar thanks for your reply, could you explain in detail? do I need to replace some code? or just add it in the loop?

Comment: Akshay meant get category's name in class. Example - `<li class="<?php get_the_category(get_the_ID()); ?>">`

Comment: @user3112938:-- Please refer this link--http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Comment: @Nix:--Please refer this link--http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category